# Adding text in an image vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am new to vb.net and I want to add some text on the image but it seems my code is not working at all.

```
Public Class Form1
  Dim Graph As Graphics
  Dim Drawbitmap As Bitmap
  Dim Brush As New Drawing.SolidBrush(Color.Black)
  Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
      Drawbitmap = New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)
      Graph = Graphics.FromImage(Drawbitmap)
      PictureBox1.Image = Drawbitmap
      Graph.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
      Graph.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Font, Brush, PictureBox1.Location)


  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Text on the image how? Something like having image in the background with some text on the foreground?

Comment: You're not refreshing the PictureBox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.  Firstly, you're not disposing of the `Bitmap` that is already in the `PictureBox`.  Secondly, you're not disposing the `Graphics` object you create to draw the text.  Thirdly, while it shouldn't be a major issue, I can't think why you'd think it was a good idea to display the `Bitmap` first and then draw the text.

Finally, and probably the reason that you're not seeing any text, is the fact that you're using `PictureBox1.Location` to specify where to draw the text.  That makes no sense because that means that the further the `PictureBox` is from the top-left of the form, the further the text will be from the top-left of the `Bitmap`.  You need to put some thought into where you actually want the text to be drawn on the `Bitmap`.

Here's some tested code that addresses all those issues:

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim img As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Width, PictureBox1.Height)

    Using g = Graphics.FromImage(img)
        g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
        g.DrawString(RichTextBox1.Text, RichTextBox1.Font, Brushes.Black, New PointF(10, 10))
    End Using

    'Dispose the existing image if there is one.'
    PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()

    PictureBox1.Image = img
End Sub
```

Note that that code also uses a system-supplied `Brush`, instead of needlessly creating one that is also not disposed.

Note that this line will only work in VB 2017:

```
PictureBox1.Image?.Dispose()
```

In earlier versions you would need an `If` statement:

```
If PictureBox1.Image IsNot Nothing Then
    PictureBox1.Image.Dispose()
End If
```

Comment: thanks @jmcilhinney works like a charm!!! and thanks for explaining it to me  it clarifies everything